# Annotate "read aloud" in Edge browser

Tags: microsoft-edge, text-to-speech

The new MS Edge browser has quite a good "read aloud" feature.

Sometimes the accent (or exclamation) on some lines don't fall on exactly the right word/syllable.

I tried making words bold in the HTML to read, but that has absolutely no effect on how it is read by the edge narrator.

Like: `Does <emphasis>this</emphasis> work?`
v.s.
`Does this <emphasis>work</emphasis>?`

Is there maybe some way to annotate text/html so that the narrator can put the accent on a different word?

Comment: https://www.w3.org/TR/html-aria/

Comment: wow, I didn't even know about ARIA. unfortunately, from what I can see, this just annotates the different elements in the web page. I was more looking for a way to change where the stress of a sentence happens for a screen reader.

Comment: Speech readers usually use [Speech Synthesis Markup Language (SSML) Version](https://www.w3.org/TR/speech-synthesis11/) which looks more like : `<emphasis> very </emphasis> sunny today`.

Comment: @harrymc ok, I've changed it to <emphasis>

Comment: @harrymc Thanks for pointing me to SSML. This is more or less what I was looking for (except that Edge cant do it). So I've got a whole rabbit hole of options to check out now

Comment: Edge does support it, in a way. See my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Microsoft Edge supports
[Speech Synthesis Markup Language (SSML)](https://www.w3.org/TR/speech-synthesis11/)
since Version 1607 (Anniversary Update),
with syntax like : `<emphasis> very </emphasis> sunny today`.

The implementation seems to be oriented toward JavaScript via the
[SpeechSynthesizer.SpeakSsml(String) Method](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.speech.synthesis.speechsynthesizer.speakssml?view=netframework-4.8).

For more information see:

- [Introducing the Speech Synthesis API in Microsoft Edge](https://blogs.windows.com/msedgedev/2016/06/01/introducing-speech-synthesis-api/)
- [Improve synthesis with Speech Synthesis Markup Language (SSML)](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/speech-service/speech-synthesis-markup)